# Page speed проверки Кэширование сторонних скриптов

Tags: кэширование, pagespeed-insights

PageSpeed выдал информации по проверки кеширования:

> **Если указывать в заголовках HTTP дату или срок действия статических ресурсов, браузер будет загружать уже полученные ранее ресурсы с локального диска, а не из Интернета.**
>
> Используйте кеш браузера для следующих ресурсов:
>   http://code.jivosite.com/script/widget/168019 (не указан срок действия)
>   https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js (60 минут)
>   http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 часа)

Скажите как настроит кэширование для данных скриптов если они не находятся на сервере? 
Может их нужно вывести в отдельный JS файл и кэшировать его? (Хотя я думаю, что это глупо т.к. судя по адресу сервер обращается с начала к ним)

Comment: Можете попробовать поискать CDN сервер с этими скриптами.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V 6 И что мне это даст? Можете расписать порядок, как делать!

Comment: если использовать CDN сервера и брать скрипты у них, то у Вас не будет проблем с кэшированием. Так как в этом и суть CDN сервера, он сам выставляет правильные заголвки, а как только оригинал скрипта изменится зальет себе новый. Но вообще, гугл говорит раз Вы используете сторонние скрипты смеритесь с этим. Это всего лишь рекомендации, а не правила.